# load png using node.js causing gibberish/binary

Tags: node.js, readfile

I'm trying to load an png into a buffer so I can pass it to another library to print it out(https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp). However instead of printing out the image, it prints of pages of gibberish. Meanwhile, PDF/txt files work fine, so my suspicion is I'm not handling the image buffer properly.

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(require('./address').file_name, "", function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }

    var msg = {
        "operation-attributes-tag": {
            "requesting-user-name": "William",
            "job-name": "My Test Job",
      "document-format":  require('./address').document_format

        },
        data: data
    };
    printer.execute("Print-Job", msg, function(err, res){

    if (err){
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
    });

  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: not sure where the `prints pages of gibberish` is happening...and can't check all of your code because no idea what `printer.execute` is or does. But when I run your code (with some random file) and get to the `console.log(data)`, I'm getting exactly what I would expect: `Buffer(4124) [99, 111, 110, 115, ...`

Comment: Thanks @David784. The printer.execute is calling this method https://github.com/williamkapke/ipp.

Comment: Ah...not going to be much help there I don't think...I don't have a printer. Sounds to me as if it's a `document-format` issue though. That library might not support printing `application/png` files directly...a quick search through their repo, the only values I'm seeing are `application/pdf`.